# Notification in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, notifications, windows-phone

I want to generate notifications from the windows phone app .Which type of notifications should be used?Give me some links where I can get complete details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Toasts, you can show the notification at the top of the screen.

For Reference of Toasts, Refer this link to display the notification

> **[Toasts for displaying the Notification in windows phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662938%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)**

And for Send and Receive the notification in windows phone please go her.

> **[How to send and Receive the notification in windows phone.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202967%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)**

I hope you get the Answer.